# Force clause on Entity Framework Where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, timestamp

I have to make my app [indepotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). In order to make my updates so, I implemented in my entities a timestamp field, because if a given operation happens to be executed twice the "where id=10 and timestamp=0x008787" will match zero results and nothing will be updated in the database.

The thing is: how can i make the EF include the "extra clause"? because so far the underlying query is always "where id=10"

Comment: A small code sample would make answering a lot easier.

Comment: Which version? Code-first, Model-First? What type is the timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code-first you can place a `[ConcurrencyCheck]` attribute on a property to include it in the WHERE clause.

For keys this is implied, as well as for special TimeStamp properties. Not clear where your property fits in.